# If a bounty question doesn't award bounty to any answer, what will happen to bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

In the case specified on the title, which answer will receive the bounty? What if a bounty question has just one answer? Will it get the bounty worth?

Answer (score 1):

If the person who offered the bounty did not award it to an answer, the highest-voted answer with a score of two or higher that was posted after the bounty has been set will get half the bounty. If the question author has accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer will be awared the full bounty regardless of its score or when it was posted. If there are no such answers, nobody will get it and the bounty will just expire.

Comment: I added some things to make it accurate and stand on its own, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Of course I don't mind, thanks for your edit!

Comment: Cheers, usually it's useless to repeat answer in duplicates, but in this case I think it's OK.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind.